# Get all possible boolean sequences for a given list length

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

Given a random list length, how can I efficiently get all possible sequences of boolean values, except strings that are all *True* or all *False*?

For instance, given the number 3 it should return something like the following.

```
[True, False, False],
[True, True, False],
[True, False, True],
[False, True, False],
[False, True, True],
[False, False, True],
```

Is there already a known function that does this?

The order that it returns the sequences in is not important. I mainly just need a number of how many sequences are possible for a given list length.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many booleans are in your list, you will always only have two permutations where all booleans are the same. Either they're all `True`, or they're all `False`.

Comment: If you have 3 booleans, then the number of permutations that do not contain all equivalent elements would be `(2 ** 3) - 2`, or more generally `(2 ** num_bools) - 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a maths question, **unless you need the sequences themselves**. If you do, there is a neat python solution:

```
from itertools import product

[seq for seq in product((True, False), repeat=3)][1:-1]
```

The list comprehension will contain **all possible sequences**, but we don't want `(True, True, True)` and `(False, False, False)`. Conveniently, these will be the **first** and **last** element respectively, so we can simply discard them, using slicing from **1** to **-1**.

For sequences with different lengths, just change the "**repeat**" optional argument of the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a function to determine this. Simple math will do the trick.

```
2**n - 2 

2 because there are only two options (True/False)
n is your list length
-2 because you want to exclude the all True and all False results
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a maths question, but here goes:

The number of total options is equal to the multiplication of the number of options per position, so, if you receive 3 as input:

```
index[0] could be true or false - 2
index[1] could be true or false - 2
index[2] could be true or false - 2
index has a total of 6 options.
```